# Why do the first 3 mouse clicks behave odd?

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

When I try the following code I get some issue about button click event:

```
from Tkinter import *
def hello(event):
    print("Single Click, Button-l") 
widget = Button(None, text='Mouse Clicks')
widget.pack()
widget.bind('<Button-1>', hello) 
widget.mainloop()
```

In the first click nothing happens, in the second click, it writes to kernel two times `"Single Click"`, in the third click nothing happens, in the fourth click and following clicks everything is OK.

Why do the first 3 clicks have this issue?

Edit:
Problem is that i was using Spyder IDE. Went back to good old terminal and everything is OK.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem you're having, with the above code.

Comment: The normal, proper way to make a Button respond to mouse clicks is to give it a `command=` option, NOT by binding events.

Comment: @Nae seriously? :D

Comment: @jasonharper tried that too but i still have the same error.

Comment: @mystic09 Yes, sounds to me you have a broken mouse.

Comment: Your code works fine for me too.